# Criar código para atualizar Schema

Tags: mysql

Uso o Mysql WorkBench para manipular meus banco de dados e tabelas MySQL.

Quando exporto a tabela, ele me gera um código semelhante ao código abaixo:

```
    CREATE TABLE `entrada` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idProduto` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `quant` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chave` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `online` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=303 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

O que quero é criar um código +- assim:

```
if !idProduto then create column idProduto int not null;
if !data then create column data date not null;
```

Verifica se já existe o campo e, caso negativo, cria o mesmo na tabela. Assim, quando eu fizer modificações no meu banco de dados local, fica mais fácil de atualizar nos bancos dos clientes, evitando assim, falhas na atualização.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o seguinte código:

```
IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
             AND table_schema = 'db_name'
             AND column_name = 'columnname')  THEN

  ALTER TABLE `TableName` ADD `ColumnName` int(1) NOT NULL default '0';

END IF;
```

Caso alguém saiba de uma solução mais prática, fico aguardando antes de selecionar essa resposta.